# How to store values excluding duplicate values in a column set as a compound unique key

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a playlist_songs table, in which I have playlist_id and song_id.

The two columns are set to a compound unique key,
You can add several songs at once by receiving songId as an array in the body.

I have tried like below.

```
  'INSERT INTO playlists_songs (playlist_id, song_id)
   VALUES (44,18),(44,21)'
```

The following error occurred.

```
   driverError: Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '44-18' for key 'playlists_songs.PK_playlists_songs_playlist_id_song_id'
```

The error seems to be caused by already having duplicate values of 44-18 in the table.

In this case, is there a way to store the rest of the values except for duplicate keys?
I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a table contains a unique index, adding duplicate values ​​to that index causes an error.

To avoid declaring the duplicate item error in the unique index, use the INSERT IGNORE command instead of the INSERT command.

If a record does not duplicate another record, then MySQL has inserted it normally.

If there is a duplicate record, the IGNORE keyword tells MySQL to ignore that value without reporting an error.

The following example does not declare any error for inserting duplicate items in unique fields, and the insertion of duplicate items is prevented: